# Why switch the culture of current thread dose not cause to switch the UI language base on the resource files?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My MVC project has 2 resource file for its 2 language (`lang.fa.resx` and `lang.resx`) and every things **works well until i run it on the local** machine (the language of the site changes when I change the language by a drop down list in the homepage).

**But when i upload it on the server** it dose not work!

It seems:

- Culture changes currectly
- Language dose not change

---

**What i did:**

**A)**
I put the following codes to the body of the homepage to test the **culture value of the current thread**:

```
@Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name
@Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name
```

Result:

It show

```
fa-IR
fa-IR
```

and

```
en-US
en-US
```

according to the selected language in the drop down list. But the language of the site dose not change!

**B)** 
I built and **re-uploaded the `dll` file** of the resource project to the server

**C)** 
I checked value of the **culture cookie** »» It changes correctly.

---

What do you think about this problem? Why it works on the local machine but dose not works when it is online on the server machine?

Comment: I think it needs a dose of debugging

Comment: Thank you @KeithNicholas, I found my mistake! There are some folder in the bin folder (name of them are en ru fa fr...). I should re-upload them to the server too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason of the problem:

Before i was just attending to the output `DLL` files of the main sub-projects in the solution explorer (class libraries and main web project) that they would be built in the root of the `bin folder`.

**But**, also **there are some folders in the bin folder** (name of them are `en` `ru` `fa` `fr`...). **Also I should re-upload them** to the server each time i re-build my project. I do this and everything become right.